# Ethereum Crowdsale Tutorial - Can't Transfer Ether to Crowdsale in Solo TestNet - The Contract Won't Allow This Transaction to Be Processed

Tags: mist, tokens, contract-debugging, gas-price, crowdsale

Im sure this is a very simple problem that one of the brilliant geniuses on this site should be able to answer! I am following the tutorial for Crowdsale found on the Ethereum website 
https://www.ethereum.org
To complete this tutorial first I created a custom token using the code found here:
https://www.ethereum.org/token

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

                interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

                contract DudeCoin {
                    // Public variables of the token
                    string public name;
                    string public symbol;
                    uint8 public decimals = 2;
                    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
                    uint256 public totalSupply;

                    // This creates an array with all balances
                    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
                    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

                    // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
                    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

                    // This notifies clients about the amount burnt
                    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

                    /**
                     * Constrctor function
                     *
                     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
                     */
                    function DudeCoin(
                        uint256 initialSupply,
                        string tokenName,
                        string tokenSymbol
                    ) public {
                        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
                        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
                        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
                        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
                    }

                    /**
                     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
                     */
                    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
                        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
                        require(_to != 0x0);
                        // Check if the sender has enough
                        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
                        // Check for overflows
                        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
                        // Save this for an assertion in the future
                        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
                        // Subtract from the sender
                        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
                        // Add the same to the recipient
                        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
                        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
                        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
                        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
                    }

                    /**
                     * Transfer tokens
                     *
                     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
                     *
                     * @param _to The address of the recipient
                     * @param _value the amount to send
                     */
                    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
                        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
                    }

                    /**
                     * Transfer tokens from other address
                     *
                     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
                     *
                     * @param _from The address of the sender
                     * @param _to The address of the recipient
                     * @param _value the amount to send
                     */
                    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
                        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
                        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
                        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
                        return true;
                    }

                    /**
                     * Set allowance for other address
                     *
                     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
                     *
                     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
                     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
                     */
                    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
                        returns (bool success) {
                        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
                        return true;
                    }

                    /**
                     * Set allowance for other address and notify
                     *
                     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
                     *
                     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
                     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
                     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
                     */
                    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
                        public
                        returns (bool success) {
                        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
                        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
                            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    /**
                     * Destroy tokens
                     *
                     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
                     *
                     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
                     */
                    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
                        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
                        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
                        totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
                        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
                        return true;
                    }

                    /**
                     * Destroy tokens from other account
                     *
                     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
                     *
                     * @param _from the address of the sender
                     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
                     */
                    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
                        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
                        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
                        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
                        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
                        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
                        Burn(_from, _value);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
```

Then I created an "Association" using the code from the tutorial here:
https://www.ethereum.org/dao

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() public{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract tokenRecipient {
    event receivedEther(address sender, uint amount);
    event receivedTokens(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData);

    function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData)public{
        Token t = Token(_token);
        require(t.transferFrom(_from, this, _value));
        receivedTokens(_from, _value, _token, _extraData);
    }

    function () public payable {
        receivedEther(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
}

contract Token {
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
}

/**
 * The shareholder association contract itself
 */
contract Association is owned, tokenRecipient {

    uint public minimumQuorum;
    uint public debatingPeriodInMinutes;
    Proposal[] public proposals;
    uint public numProposals;
    Token public sharesTokenAddress;

    event ProposalAdded(uint proposalID, address recipient, uint amount, string description);
    event Voted(uint proposalID, bool position, address voter);
    event ProposalTallied(uint proposalID, uint result, uint quorum, bool active);
    event ChangeOfRules(uint newMinimumQuorum, uint newDebatingPeriodInMinutes, address newSharesTokenAddress);

    struct Proposal {
        address recipient;
        uint amount;
        string description;
        uint votingDeadline;
        bool executed;
        bool proposalPassed;
        uint numberOfVotes;
        bytes32 proposalHash;
        Vote[] votes;
        mapping (address => bool) voted;
    }

    struct Vote {
        bool inSupport;
        address voter;
    }

    // Modifier that allows only shareholders to vote and create new proposals
    modifier onlyShareholders {
        require(sharesTokenAddress.balanceOf(msg.sender) > 0);
        _;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor function
     *
     * First time setup
     */
    function Association(Token sharesAddress, uint minimumSharesToPassAVote, uint minutesForDebate) public payable {
        changeVotingRules(sharesAddress, minimumSharesToPassAVote, minutesForDebate);
    }

    /**
     * Change voting rules
     *
     * Make so that proposals need to be discussed for at least `minutesForDebate/60` hours
     * and all voters combined must own more than `minimumSharesToPassAVote` shares of token `sharesAddress` to be executed
     *
     * @param sharesAddress token address
     * @param minimumSharesToPassAVote proposal can vote only if the sum of shares held by all voters exceed this number
     * @param minutesForDebate the minimum amount of delay between when a proposal is made and when it can be executed
     */
    function changeVotingRules(Token sharesAddress, uint minimumSharesToPassAVote, uint minutesForDebate) public onlyOwner {
        sharesTokenAddress = Token(sharesAddress);
        if (minimumSharesToPassAVote == 0 ) minimumSharesToPassAVote = 1;
        minimumQuorum = minimumSharesToPassAVote;
        debatingPeriodInMinutes = minutesForDebate;
        ChangeOfRules(minimumQuorum, debatingPeriodInMinutes, sharesTokenAddress);
    }

    /**
     * Add Proposal
     *
     * Propose to send `weiAmount / 1e18` ether to `beneficiary` for `jobDescription`. `transactionBytecode ? Contains : Does not contain` code.
     *
     * @param beneficiary who to send the ether to
     * @param weiAmount amount of ether to send, in wei
     * @param jobDescription Description of job
     * @param transactionBytecode bytecode of transaction
     */
    function newProposal(
        address beneficiary,
        uint weiAmount,
        string jobDescription,
        bytes transactionBytecode
    )   public
        onlyShareholders
        returns (uint proposalID)
    {
        proposalID = proposals.length++;
        Proposal storage p = proposals[proposalID];
        p.recipient = beneficiary;
        p.amount = weiAmount;
        p.description = jobDescription;
        p.proposalHash = keccak256(beneficiary, weiAmount, transactionBytecode);
        p.votingDeadline = now + debatingPeriodInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        p.executed = false;
        p.proposalPassed = false;
        p.numberOfVotes = 0;
        ProposalAdded(proposalID, beneficiary, weiAmount, jobDescription);
        numProposals = proposalID+1;

        return proposalID;
    }

    /**
     * Add proposal in Ether
     *
     * Propose to send `etherAmount` ether to `beneficiary` for `jobDescription`. `transactionBytecode ? Contains : Does not contain` code.
     * This is a convenience function to use if the amount to be given is in round number of ether units.
     *
     * @param beneficiary who to send the ether to
     * @param etherAmount amount of ether to send
     * @param jobDescription Description of job
     * @param transactionBytecode bytecode of transaction
     */
    function newProposalInEther(
        address beneficiary,
        uint etherAmount,
        string jobDescription,
        bytes transactionBytecode
    )   public                  
        onlyShareholders
        returns (uint proposalID)
    {
        return newProposal(beneficiary, etherAmount * 1 ether, jobDescription, transactionBytecode);
    }

    /**
     * Check if a proposal code matches
     *
     * @param proposalNumber ID number of the proposal to query
     * @param beneficiary who to send the ether to
     * @param weiAmount amount of ether to send
     * @param transactionBytecode bytecode of transaction
     */
    function checkProposalCode(
        uint proposalNumber,
        address beneficiary,
        uint weiAmount,
        bytes transactionBytecode
    )   public
        constant
        returns (bool codeChecksOut)
    {
        Proposal storage p = proposals[proposalNumber];
        return p.proposalHash == keccak256(beneficiary, weiAmount, transactionBytecode);
    }

    /**
     * Log a vote for a proposal
     *
     * Vote `supportsProposal? in support of : against` proposal #`proposalNumber`
     *
     * @param proposalNumber number of proposal
     * @param supportsProposal either in favor or against it
     */
    function vote(
        uint proposalNumber,
        bool supportsProposal
    )   public
        onlyShareholders
        returns (uint voteID)
    {
        Proposal storage p = proposals[proposalNumber];
        require(p.voted[msg.sender] != true);

        voteID = p.votes.length++;
        p.votes[voteID] = Vote({inSupport: supportsProposal, voter: msg.sender});
        p.voted[msg.sender] = true;
        p.numberOfVotes = voteID +1;
        Voted(proposalNumber,  supportsProposal, msg.sender);
        return voteID;
    }

    /**
     * Finish vote
     *
     * Count the votes proposal #`proposalNumber` and execute it if approved
     *
     * @param proposalNumber proposal number
     * @param transactionBytecode optional: if the transaction contained a bytecode, you need to send it
     */
    function executeProposal(uint proposalNumber, bytes transactionBytecode) public {
        Proposal storage p = proposals[proposalNumber];

        require(now > p.votingDeadline                                             // If it is past the voting deadline
            && !p.executed                                                          // and it has not already been executed
            && p.proposalHash == keccak256(p.recipient, p.amount, transactionBytecode)); // and the supplied code matches the proposal...


        // ...then tally the results
        uint quorum = 0;
        uint yea = 0;
        uint nay = 0;

        for (uint i = 0; i <  p.votes.length; ++i) {
            Vote storage v = p.votes[i];
            uint voteWeight = sharesTokenAddress.balanceOf(v.voter);
            quorum += voteWeight;
            if (v.inSupport) {
                yea += voteWeight;
            } else {
                nay += voteWeight;
            }
        }

        require(quorum >= minimumQuorum); // Check if a minimum quorum has been reached

        if (yea > nay ) {
            // Proposal passed; execute the transaction

            p.executed = true;
            require(p.recipient.call.value(p.amount)(transactionBytecode));

            p.proposalPassed = true;
        } else {
            // Proposal failed
            p.proposalPassed = false;
        }

        // Fire Events
        ProposalTallied(proposalNumber, yea - nay, quorum, p.proposalPassed);
    }
}
```

Then, I created the "crowdsale" using the code from the tutorial here:
https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface token {
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) public ;
}

contract Crowdsale7 {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal;
    uint public amountRaised;
    uint public deadline;
    uint public price;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool fundingGoalReached = false;
    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;

    event GoalReached(address recipient, uint totalAmountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Setup the owner
     */
    function Crowdsale7(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint fundingGoalInEthers,
        uint durationInMinutes,
        uint etherCostOfEachToken,
        address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) public {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
    }

    /**
     * Fallback function
     *
     * The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract
     */
    function () public payable {
        require(!crowdsaleClosed);
        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
    }

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /**
     * Check if goal was reached
     *
     * Checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign
     */
    function checkGoalReached() public afterDeadline {
        if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
            fundingGoalReached = true;
            GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
        }
        crowdsaleClosed = true;
    }


    /**
     * Withdraw the funds
     *
     * Checks to see if goal or time limit has been reached, and if so, and the funding goal was reached,
     * sends the entire amount to the beneficiary. If goal was not reached, each contributor can withdraw
     * the amount they contributed.
     */
    function safeWithdrawal() public afterDeadline {
        if (!fundingGoalReached) {
            uint amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
            if (amount > 0) {
                if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
                } else {
                    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
                FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            } else {
                //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
                fundingGoalReached = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I execute the crowdsale, I am unable to successfully transfer funds into the Crowdsale account and I get the following error

[image: Ethereum Mist Error]

This has become somewhat frustrating because I have followed the instructions in the tutorials to the letter but am unable to get this (relatively) simple example working. All I need to do is create a basic crowdsale for the purchase of "DudeCoins". If one of the eminently brilliant geniuses on this site would point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the transaction would not process because I had forgotten to fund the crowdsale with my custom tokens called "DudeCoins". After funding my crowdsale with "DudeCoins" the Crowdsale was able to accept Ethers for Tokens normally.